# React: setState - which is more correct?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react class component that has a state object and I want to update the object with setState. I can get the state to update correctly two different ways and would like to know if one is more correct than the other.

```
this.state = {
  people: {
    name: "",
    typeofComponent: "class",
  }
};

onChange = e => {

  // option 1
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    people: {
        ...prevState.people, name: e.target.value 
    }
  }));

  // option 2
  this.setState({ people: { name: e.target.value }});
}
```

Comment: These do two totally different things. What do you mean by "correct", exactly? The first gives you `{people: {typeofComponent: "class", name: e.target.value}}` whereas the second gives you `{people: {name: e.target.value}}`, a totally different structure that no longer has `typeofComponent`. Probably the second isn't correct in the sense that it changes your state structure.

Comment: You should try to flatten your state as much as possible to prevent this kind of question ;) Here option 1 is the only valid one as stated in cmgchess answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second option would work if the state has only 1 field (`name` in your case). If you set that way it will overwrite the whole `people`. That's why we need to use  spread operator inorder to make sure the other states are not lost

```js
let a = {
  people: {
    name: "",
    typeofComponent: "class",
  }
}

let newName = 'newname'

let withSpread= {people:{...a.people,name:newName}}

let withoutSpread = {people:{name:newName}}

console.log(withSpread)
console.log(withoutSpread)
```